# Google sheet conditional importrange

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

I am trying to import rows from a sheet to another depending on the textual value of a column. After some research i find 2 methods to accomplish this : 
coupling the importrange function with the query function or the filter function. So, I try this formula in my sheet

```
=Query(importrange("URL";"Customer Data!a2:X");"select*where col6="textual_value"")
```

I already split my formula in 2 part so I could test my importrange function and it works, `=importrange("URL";"Customer Data!a2:X")`
however it export all the sheet.

Considering this, I think there is an issue with my Query syntax.

Is there anyone who know how to solve this ?

Comment: as the part `"select * where Col6='textual_value'";0` I've edited some small things. From `col6` capitalize c to be `Col6` and `"textual_value"` " to be just ' `'textual_value'` and add more `;0` if your range don't include headers, yet it still not necessary I think. I hope it'll work

Comment: It works, THANKS A LOT !!!

Comment: I'm happy to help. Find out more about `Query()` https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage here. And I think you can close this question now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use this formula instead:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("URL";"Customer Data!A2:X");"SELECT * WHERE Col6 = 'textual_value'; 0")
```

#### Reference

- [Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)